# FromBody doesn't seem to be working on C# API PUT call and is always null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I seem to be going around in circles on this and from my searches, I seem to only be able to find solutions for more "complex" problems.

I want to pass an int and a JSON array of strings to the API and then process them. However, it says the string is in the wrong format. So I tried dumbing it down to just deal with a simple string, however it just returns as null. The id is picked up fine and passes that back if I change the return to the id, but with items, it always says it is null.

Looking at the request, the payload looks fine.

**Headers**
[image: Headers]

**Payload**
[image: Payload]

**Response**
[image: Response]

**Debug view**
[image: Debug]

Javascript (JQuery)

```js
function saveHealthCheck() {
    var cID = $('#<%= hfHealthCheck.ClientID %>').val();

    var jsonstr = '"Hello World!"'

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/api/AppliesTo/") %>' + cID,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: jsonstr,
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
     });
}
```

C# API

```cs
public string Put(int id, [FromBody] string items)
{
    //Just to test
    return items;
}
```

Comment: `dataType` *The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.* - by setting this to json, jquery expects your C# to return json; it's not, so giving an error.  Check the network tab to see exactly what *is* being returned - the service might be working, but failing at the jquery step.   Change to `dataType: 'text'` for plain text.

Comment: Are you able to step through the server-side code?   What are you using to debug your C#?  VS? VSCode? Notepad?  This will tell you what's going on there.

Comment: I have been stepping through, so apologises, for being a bit ambiguous. null is being passed into the API, not just out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this is different to what others have suggested, but this works.

**Javascript**

```
function saveHealthCheck() {
    var cID = $('#<%= hfHealthCheck.ClientID %>').val();
    var jsonstr = { "id": cID, "apps": ["Hello World!", "Hello World2!"] };

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/api/AppliesTo/") %>',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: jsonstr,
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
     });
}
```

**API**

```
        public List<string> Put([FromBody] MyItems items)
        {
            return items.apps;
        }
```

**Model**

```
    public class MyItems
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<string> apps { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you for the input in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass string as object via POST or PUT. Your option is to wrap it into a data object.

Updated JS script just for example:

```
function saveHealthCheck() {
    var cID = $('#<%= hfHealthCheck.ClientID %>').val();

    var jsonstr = {items:["Hello World!","Hello World2!"]};

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/api/AppliesTo/") %>' + cID,
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonstr),
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
     });
}
```

Data model class:

```
public class MyItems
{
  public List<string> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Updated Api:

```
public List<string> Put(int id, [FromBody] MyItems items)
{
    //Just to test
    return items.Items;
}
```

Comment: Tried those changes and it is still doing the same. Also realised that I was a bit ambiguous. null is being passed into the API not just out of the API.

Comment: Can you show what you have in the body of your transaction? Can you make a screenshot from you browser network message to your api?

Comment: Added images to question.

Comment: @PS I modified my answer. Check JS section I changed jsonstr into an object and applied JSON.stringify before sending it out. Depends on the JS version you use, you might need to replace ```var``` with ```const```

Comment: That didn't work either. But I have solved it, will post my solution separately